# What exactly is a Frieze group and how would you find the isometries preserving one?

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups, dihedral-groups

So far, I've come across several examples of frieze groups, but I've not yet come across an understandable definition of what they are. I've also been asked questions that ask me to state the isometries preserving said frieze groups and I don't really understand how I should know what these are either. Could someone please explain this to me?

Many thanks.